# Parameterizing $C$ in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $C$ be the boundary with vertices at the points $0,3i,-4.$

[image]

Is the following parameterization correct?

$C_1:z_1(t) = it, 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 3,$

$C_2=z_2(t) = 3i(4-t)-4(t-3), 3 \leqslant t \leqslant 4,$

$C_3 = z_3(t) = -4(t-3), 4 \leqslant t \leqslant 3$

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works fine but looks odd. To parametrize the points from a to b you generally use $a(1−t)+tb$  so that if t = 0 you are at a and if t = 1 you are at b.